# How to swipe between fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have a `section_home` layout that **shows a picture**. Then I made another layout called `section_home_two` that **shows a different picture**. In my code I have a class called `HomeFragment` for the `section_home` layout. The second java class is called `PreviewsFragment` for the `section_home_two` layout.

Is there anyway you can make **HomeFragment** swipe horizontally to **PreviewsFragment**? Is there anyway to merge them?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use a `ViewPager` to swipe between the fragments.

Follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html to get the ViewPager working, and then change the number of pages to 2:

```
private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;
```

And use this `PagerAdapter` instead of the one in the sample:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return new HomeFragment(); // The ViewPager will show this fragment first
        else
            return new PreviewsFragment; // and will allow you to swipe to this one and back.
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to swipe horizontally back and forth between the two fragments. if you're using a factory method to create your fragments, use that instead of the `return new HomeFragment();` and `return new PreviewsFragment();` lines.